# Why does console.logging outside a function work as intended, but doing so inside one marks my value as undefined?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing the coding challenge from freecodecamp.org. Here it is:

```
//create a function where you pass a name and a property, and the value of the prop will be returned

var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        
        if (name == contacts[i].firstName) {
            
            return console.log(contacts[i][prop]) || console.log('No such property'); 
            
             }
         } 
         
    return console.log('No such contact');
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

My problem is that instead of console.logging the function itself, I wanted to do it inside the function so the values are strings. However, this kept marking undefined and I don't get why. Here's the correct form of the code

```
//create a function where you pass a name and a property, and the value of the prop will be returned

var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        
        if (name == contacts[i].firstName) {
            
            return contacts[i][prop] || 'No such property'; 
            
             }
         } 
         
    return console.log('No such contact');
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
```

Also, I don't get how an 'or' (||) statement works as an 'else' statement and why does the last return only returns the value if the if statement is false. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not return a console.log, because the console.log function does not return anything, thats why it returns undefined. Console.log function is never ment to be used in a return.

Use console log before the return and still return the value after the logging.

```
const func = () => {
    const myValue = 10;

    console.log(myValue);
    return myValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, why doesn't it return anything?

Comment: @santti_alter The purpose of this is to output something to the console, since it does not mutate or do anything with the inserted value, there is no point to actually returning anything. It is only for development purposes and not recommended to be used in actual production

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` always returns `undefined`, Do in this way:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    
        if (name == contacts[i].firstName) {
        
            return contacts[i][prop]; 
        
        }
    } 
     
    return null;
}

console.log( lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes") ?? 'No such contact');
```

Comment: Could be because the indenting makes it look like you got the logic wrong. It looks like the return null is inside the for loop.

Comment: @seesharper Such a nice point!  thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` returns `undefined` because it doesn't actually return anything. Its main purpose is to print something.  So, it is not advisable to use `return` with `console.log`.

The `||` OR statement, evaluates the 1st expression first, and depending upon it, it evaluates 2nd expression.
For Example, `exp1 || exp2` will return `exp1` if value of `exp1` evaluates to `true`, else, it returns `exp2`.

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    if (name == contacts[i].firstName) {
      return contacts[i][prop] || 'No such prop';
    }
  }

  return 'No such contact';

}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "dislikes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sharnav", "likes"));
```